# Sending request to Starlettle Test client with httpx library

Tags: python, starlette

Hi guys I am using [starlett test client](https://www.starlette.io/testclient/). Is it possible to send request using httpx library to this test client.

My use case is I have 2 apps. Say,`App 1` and `App2`. for single app testing for App 1. Test client works fine. But in some cases App1 Calls App2 using httpx and library. In this case I don't want to run the App2 server. So wanted to know whether there is some way to call the App2 test client using httpx.

Comment: in technology `client-server` client can only send `request` to server which sends back `response`. You can't send `request` to client. You would have to convert `client` into `server`